# How to get a VanityGenerated public address for a hardware wallet? (Ledger Nano S)

Tags: vanity-address, hardware-wallet, vanitygen

I recently bought a Nano Ledger S and have not opened or set it up yet. I read that you can use a VanityGen to create a Vanity public address. How would I do this for my Nano Ledger, if I want to make sure that I keep my keys 100% safe?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use custom keys with ledger since the addresses Ledger uses are all derived from your (randomly generated) seed.